# Vertically align two elements in a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to vertically align these two "containers" below (black and blue), where, for example, the distance A should be the same as B. I've already tried to use `top` or `below`, but it isn't responsive. Is there any other way to do it and still have the facebook icon centered (which, for some reason, didn't center on Safari, but works just fine with Chrome)?

[image]

### Code

You can also see it in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7kt3y5ya/) ([full screen](https://jsfiddle.net/7kt3y5ya/embedded/result/)).

```css
.content {
  background: yellow;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.black-container {
  background: black;
  display: flex;
}

.social-button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.blue-container {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-line-icons/2.4.1/css/simple-line-icons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="black-container col-xs-6">
      <button type="button" name="button" class="social-button"><i class="icon-social-facebook"></i></button>
      <button type="button" name="button" class="social-button"><i class="icon-social-facebook"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="blue-container col-xs-6 text-right">
      <p>testing <a href="">TEST</a> testing</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use flexbox for your row, and don't forget to add prefix for cross browser

```css
.content {
  background: yellow;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.row {
  /* Safari 6.1+ */
  display: -webkit-box;
  /* IE 10 */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  /* standard*/
  display: flex;
  /* Safari 6.1+ */
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  /* IE 10 */
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  /* standard*/
  align-items: center;
}

.black-container {
  background: black;
  display: flex;
}

.social-button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.blue-container {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-line-icons/2.4.1/css/simple-line-icons.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container content">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="black-container col-xs-6">
        <button type="button" name="button" class="social-button"><i class="icon-social-facebook"></i></button>
        <button type="button" name="button" class="social-button"><i class="icon-social-facebook"></i></button>
      </div>

      <div class="blue-container col-xs-6 text-right">
        <p>testing <a href="">TEST</a> testing</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using Flexbox and remove `display:flex` from `black-container` and `social-button`

```css
.content {
  background: yellow;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
}

.black-container {
  background: black;
}

.social-button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.blue-container {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
.blue-container p {
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-line-icons/2.4.1/css/simple-line-icons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container content">
    <div class="row row-eq-height">
        <div class="black-container col-xs-6">
            <button type="button" name="button" class="social-button"><i class="icon-social-facebook"></i></button>
            <button type="button" name="button" class="social-button"><i class="icon-social-facebook"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="blue-container col-xs-6 text-right">
            <p>testing <a href="">TEST</a> testing</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! It worked, but the circle isn't positioned to the left as before. Since it solves the main problem, I'm up voting your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

A possibility is to define a flexbox for the row. I created a separate class for this purpose and added it to the div having class `.row`

```css
.content {
  background: yellow;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.row.black-n-blue {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.black-container {
  background: black;
  display: flex;
}

.social-button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.blue-container {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-line-icons/2.4.1/css/simple-line-icons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container content">
  <div class="row black-n-blue">

    <div class="black-container col-xs-6">
      <button type="button" name="button" class="social-button"><i class="icon-social-facebook"></i></button>
      <button type="button" name="button" class="social-button"><i class="icon-social-facebook"></i></button>
    </div>

    <div class="blue-container col-xs-6 text-right">
      <p>testing <a href="">TEST</a> testing</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! It also worked, but as Duannx answered before, I'm accepting his answer. I up voted your answer :)